# Find rows in which the column doesn't contain a "space"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pattern-matching

I'm using Postgres 9.5.  I want to search for rows in which my name column does not contain a space.  I'm a little murky on how to define a space to you, though. I thought it would just be the space bar on my keyboard, so I ran:

```
.... where name not like '% %';
```

but then I got some results like this:

```
 | JASON FALKNER
```

That sure looks like a space to me, but there are probably some other things going on. Is there a better way I can scan for rows in which my name column doesn't contain a space?

Using a regexp, `not (name ~ '\s')` still returned columns that looked like they had a space.

Using:

```
select cast(name as bytea) ... where name not like like '% %';
```

returned:

```
\x4a41534f4ec2a0424c414b45
```

However, I'm still a little unclear how I use that data to figure out how to screen spaces from my results.

I tried `where not (name ~ '[[:space:]]')'` and it's returning "JASON BLAKE" with the same byte sequence above, `\x4a41534f4ec2a0424c414b45`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you provide explicitly the characters you want to be considered as "white space" and excluded to a regex:

```
where name !~ '[ \t\v\b\r\n\u00a0]'
```

Characters:

```
\s         white space (space, \r, \n, \t, \v, \f)
' '        space
\t         (horizontal) tab
\v         vertical tab
\b         backspace
\r         carriage return
\n         newline
\f         form feed
\u00a0     non-breaking space
---
```

See the docs for [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

In your example, note that `\xC2A0` is the UTF-8 representation of [Non breaking space (00A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

Comment: `\s` isn't "space", `\s` is a character class that is defined as `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` your `\t \v \n \r` are all redundant.

Comment: @EvanCarroll True, it's not just space. I couldn't find the exact definition, thus my suggestion to explicitly use all characters the OP wants to exclude.

Comment: space is `[ ]` :)

Answer (score 5):

There exist a multitude of space characters as per the following Unicode listing:

[Unicode Characters in the 'Separator, Space' Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm)

I would extend the where clause in [ypercubeᵀᴹ's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168234/1192) to:
*(edit: added \ at the beginning of the string]*

```
where name !~ '[\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202f\u205f\u3000]'
```

Characters:

```
u0020 SPACE
u00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
u1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
u2000 EN QUAD
u2001 EM QUAD
U2002 EN SPACE
u2003 EM SPACE
u2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
u2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
u2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
u2007 FIGURE SPACE
u2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
u2009 THIN SPACE
u200A HAIR SPACE
u202f NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
u205f MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
u3000 IDEGRAPHIC SPACE
```

.... and test and test again.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried `where not (name ~ '[[:space:]]')'` and it's returning "JASON BLAKE" with the same byte sequence above, `\x4a41534f4ec2a0424c414b45`.

I'll assume that byte sequence is UTF8:

```
SELECT
  string,
  string NOT LIKE '% %' AS simple,
  string ~ '^\S*$' AS regexp_oppr,
  string !~ '[[:space:]]' AS regexp_oppr_posix
FROM ( VALUES
  ('THIS HAS A SPACE IN THE MIDDLE'),
  ('   BEFORE'),
  ('AFTER    '),
  ('NONE_NONE_NONE'),
  (' | JASON FALKNER'),
  (convert_from('\x4a41534f4ec2a0424c414b45'::bytea, 'UTF8'))
) AS t(string);
```

That outputs this

```
             string             | simple | regexp_oppr | regexp_oppr_posix 
--------------------------------+--------+-------------+-------------------
 THIS HAS A SPACE IN THE MIDDLE | f      | f           | f
    BEFORE                      | f      | f           | f
 AFTER                          | f      | f           | f
 NONE_NONE_NONE                 | t      | t           | t
  | JASON FALKNER               | f      | f           | f
 JASON BLAKE                    | t      | t           | t
(6 rows)
```

If I was right to assume the `JASON BLAKE` is utf8 then all of the methods  mentioned detect the space in it (and the method of `^\S*$` which is my own addition).

Comment: I'm confused about the claim that these methods detect non-breaking space (as a space). It seems they don't. Unless you aren't claiming that.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: I think whether they get or not non-breaking space is very system-dependent (or locale-dependent). It seems *not* to work the same on a Windows or a MacOS machine, for instance.